# docker exec ... mysql -h127.0.0.1 from utils shell script doesn't work

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a shell script and want to invoke via command line the mysql client

```
cat \
  "${SQL_DIR}/mysql-schema.sql" \
  "${SQL_DIR}/privileges.sql" \
  "${SQL_DIR}/mysql-import.sql" \
  "${SQL_DIR}/after.sql" \
  | docker exec -i "${PREPARE_NAME}" mysql -h127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -uroot -proot --default-character-set=utf8
```

it tells me

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
read unix @->/var/run/docker.sock: read: connection reset by peer
```

If I do this from the command line everything works fine.

What shall I do?

Comment: Does a `docker exec "${PREPARE_NAME}" mysql -h127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -uroot -proot --default-character-set=utf8` by itself connect to mysql? Does the script fail immediately or after a while?

Comment: By itself it works. Only within a bash script it fails.

Comment: Immediately or after some processing? Does it make a difference doing the files one at a time?

Comment: Needs more information. What command used to start the MySQL server? What are variables `SQL_DIR` and `PREPARE_NAME`? What is the host OS? What version Docker (`docker version`)? What is the current folder (`pwd`)?

Comment: ```$SQL_DIR``` and ```$PREPARE_NAME``` are just variables in the script and are not necessary for reproducing the problem. ```cat ... | docker exec -i container-name mysql -h127.0.0.1 -uroot -proot``` doesn't work within a bash script. The container has a mysql client.

Answer (score 0):

You need mysql to be installed on your computer. Even if you handle Docker with the shell script: you really just need it on the computer that runs the shell script. Then you will get rid of

```
/home/.../some_bash_script.sh: line 123: mysql: command not found
```

and

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
```

On your computer, run:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```