# Docker, MySQL - command not found in .sh file

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose

I just set up a `Dockerfile` and a `docker-compose.yml`. And for some reason, Docker cannot run this script. Whenever this script is run, it goes through all SQL files and migrates that file.

```
#!/bin/bash

DB_NAME="database_name"
DB_USER="username"
DB_PASS="password"
DB_HOST="localhost"

#get current version
GET_DATABASE_VERSION="SELECT name FROM version TOP 1"
#

echo "Getting data version"
version=$(mysql -h$DB_HOST -u$DB_USER -p$DB_PASS $DB_NAME -e "SELECT name FROM version")
#trim string to get current version name
version=${version:5}
x="./config/scripts/migration/$version"
echo $version
MIGRATION_PATH="./config/scripts/migration/*"
#get migration file for newer version
for filename in $MIGRATION_PATH -maxdepth 2
do
    if [[ -f $filename ]]; then
        if [[ "$filename" > "$x" ]] || [ "$filename" == "$x" ]; then
            echo "Running migration file: $filename"
            mysql -h$DB_HOST -u$DB_USER -p$DB_PASS $DB_NAME < $filename
        fi
    fi
done
```

I keep getting error messages `./config/scripts/migrate_local.sh: line 25: mysql: command not found` which is this line `mysql -h$DB_HOST -u$DB_USER -p$DB_PASS $DB_NAME < $filename`.

How can I fix this? Here are the `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml`, I'm using `sudo docker-compose up --build` to run.

#### File *Dockerfile*

```
FROM node:8
MAINTAINER Tri Nguyen "me@mydomain.com"

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src
WORKDIR /usr/src

COPY package.json /usr/src
RUN npm install
RUN npm rebuild node-sass --force
COPY . /usr/src

EXPOSE 3000 8000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

#### File *docker-compose.yml*

```
version: "2"
services:
  universe:
    build: .
    working_dir: /usr/src
    environment:
    - NODE_ENV=default
    - PORT=3000
    volumes:
    - /usr/src
    ports:
    - "3000:3000"
    - "8000:8000"
    links:
    - redis
    - mysql

  redis:
    image: redis
    volumes:
    - /data/redis:/data

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "database_name"
      MYSQL_USER: "username"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "password"
    volumes:
    - /data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

I use `winston` as my logger. However, it doesn't work whatsoever, but `console.log` works fine. This might be the error:

```
universe_1  |   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
universe_1  |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
universe_1  |   syscall: 'connect',
universe_1  |   address: '127.0.0.1',
universe_1  |   port: 3307,
universe_1  |   fatal: true
```

Comment: where this script is running? on your `universe` image?

Comment: @EmruzHossain yeah exactly, here is the script `chmod +x ./config/scripts/dbsetup_local.sh && ./config/scripts/dbsetup_local.sh` running inside the `universe` image. I updated what I found, that's might be the error

Answer (score 5):

Your `universe` image does not have `mysql` command line tools installed. You have to install it while building the Docker image.

Try the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8
MAINTAINER Tri Nguyen "me@mydomain.com"

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src
WORKDIR /usr/src

COPY package.json /usr/src
RUN npm install
RUN npm rebuild node-sass --force
RUN set -ex; \
    apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    mysql-client

COPY . /usr/src

EXPOSE 3000 8000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Comment: Thanks. It's solved the above problem but this problem came up `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

Comment: try using `DB_HOST="127.0.0.1"` instead of `DB_HOST="localhost"`. Ref: https://help.memsql.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001215603-ERROR-2002-HY000-Can-t-connect-to-local-MySQL-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysqld-sock-

Comment: I got `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)`. I think `localhost` was correct, it's something with permission of `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`

Comment: are you able to access mysql database from local machine?

Comment: Yes it runs perfectly fine

Comment: I have modified script and docker_compose file slightly. Can you try them?
https://gist.github.com/hossainemruz/522fbcc69bee4f73fe63a3bcbff336c7
https://gist.github.com/hossainemruz/53303a48f1906610cdb8c7257cc08f53

Comment: Thanks, I tried it still giving the error, I'm gonna go back to the original `docker` way instead of `docker-compose`

Comment: It does but for some reason it keeps showing this line `while ! nc -q 1 $DB_HOST $DB_PORT </dev/null; do` - `command not found`

Comment: @TriNguyen My answer was deleted because I posted too many similar answers in different places. The solution to your problem is that you need `mysql-server` on your local machine, see [docker exec ... mysql -h127.0.0.1 from utils shell script doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70302203/11154841) which is caused by the same situation as this question here or [MySQL command line '-bash command not found'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70302633/11154841).